# Save current state after jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide a button after clicking another button but as when the page refreshed, the hidden button shows up again. I wanted to remain it hidden even if I refresh the page and show it only if I click the show button.
Any help would be much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="showhide">Show / Hide</button>
<button type="button" class="link">Link</button>
```

JS:

```
$('.showhide').click(function(){
 $('.link').hide();
});
```

Comment: use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla, thanks i'll try that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like @Kartikeya said, use localStorage.

Set it when you click the button. On page load check the value of the localStorage to update the visibility of the button.

```
$('.showhide').click(function(){
    $('.link').toggle();

    var isVisible = $('.link').is(":visible"); 
    localStorage.setItem('visible', isVisible);
});

// stored in localStorage as string, `toggle` needs boolean
var isVisible = localStorage.getItem('visible') === 'false' ? false : true;
$('.link').toggle(isVisible);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/undm500w/8/

Answer (score 6):

You can handle it on client end with localStorage by below code.
or you need to use sessionStorage at your server script.

```
if(localStorage.getItem('isHide'))
  $('.link').hide();
$('.showhide').click(function(){
  $('.link').hide();
  localStorage.setItem('isHide',true);
});
```

Comment: Question, when I click again the show it doesn't show the `link` button. How to show it again?

Comment: The easiest is to use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead of `hide`.

Comment: for that you need to use toggling event   $('.showhide').click(function(){
  $('.link').toggle();localStorage.setItem('isHide',true);
});

Answer (score 3):

If you want the button to remain hidden even after closing the browser you should consider using `localStorage`, more on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), otherwise I suggest going with `sessionStorage` which is something similar to sessions, that means that everything stored on the session storage will be removed when you close the browser. You can read about the session storage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Basically there two functions you need to use. The `getItem` and the `setItem`. This is a demonstration using the `sessionStorage` but applies for the `localStorage` too:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       if(sessionStorage.getItem('isBtnHidden')){
           $('.link').hide();
       }

       $('.link').click(function(){
          $('.link').hide();
          sessionStorage.setItem('isBtnHidden', true);
       });
   });
```

Comment: Thanks. this is also working same as the previous answer. I'll pick `localStorage` coz I wanted to hide it forever and just show it back when Clicking show button