# How can I save my data in the local storage?

Tags: javascript

I have this function that disables the button after clicking it, how can I save the state in local storage.

```
cancelado: function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  x.disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: what do you want to save to the state ? details, please.

Comment: I want the page to be disabled even if it reloads

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to include more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save data to local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743862/save-data-to-local-storage)

Comment: I bet this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want `localStorage`? Instead of asking about your attempted solution, ask about your real problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save current state after jquery click function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538465/save-current-state-after-jquery-click-function)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you change the button's state, you need to update a flag in the local storage - you could even write a function that does both in one go, e.g.

```
function setButtonDisabled(state) {
    // Update the button's state
    document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = state;
    // Set the local storage flag to match
    localStorage.setItem("myBtnState", state);
}

// Usage would be setButtonDisabled(true) to disable or
// setButtonDisabled(false) to enable
```

When you load the page, you then would need to get that state (if it exists), and update the button, e.g.

```
// On page load (or in whatever event creates the button)
window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
    // Read the saved state from local storage (if not yet saved, will be null)
    let myBtnState = localStorage.getItem("myBtnState");

    if (myBtnState != null) { // If a state has been saved...
        // ...reset the state of the button from the saved state
        document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = myBtnState == "true"; 
    }
});
```

Note that local storage can only store strings (technically DOMStrings), not booleans (or numbers, objects, functions, etc), so the value we pass in (a boolean value of `true` or `false`) will be automatically converted to `"true"` or `"false"` - hence we need to check if this value equals a string value of `"true"` to convert it back to an actual boolean value.

You can read more about the local storage API at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage).

---

I bet, however, that you have more than element that you want to save the state for. Additionally, this is a very "mechanical" solution to the problem. It would probably be better to save some sort of JSON object representing the *state* of the page, rather than the *effects* of that state.

For example, what is causing the button to be getting disabled? Lets say that it's because the user has entered a number that's too large in a form. In that case, it would be better to save the number, because then not only could we fill it back into the box, but also if no number is filled into the box, then the button shouldn't be greyed out. This also lets us change logic better - if we upped the maximum on allowed numbers, then users that come back to the page after entering numbers that used to be too small will still find the box greyed out, whereas if we had saved the number, we could perform the calculation again and realise that their number is now valid.

Comment: There are several hundred duplicates of this on Stack Overflow, only with an actual question. Please don't answer bad questions, and please don't answer obvious duplicates.