# how to save the state of button after page refresh using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

how can I save the state of toggle buttons even after the page is refreshed using jQuery. I googled it and found that we can do it using local Storage but how to apply local storage in jQuery all I could find was examples on JavaScript. please help.
Below is the code to toggle(hide/show) table columns.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $headings = $('.heading');

  $('.hide').on('click', e => {
    let $el = $('.col' + e.target.dataset.targetIndex).toggle();
    let colspan = $('table tbody tr:first > td:visible').length / $headings.length;
    $headings.prop('colspan', colspan);
  });
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="heading" colspan="7">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="7">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="7">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="7">abcd</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>

<button class="hide" data-target-index="1">1</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="2">2</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="3">3</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="4">4</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="5">5</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="6">6</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="7">7</button>
```

Comment: refer this stack overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538465/save-current-state-after-jquery-click-function

Comment: @LalitMehra Thanks for sharing but its not working for me :(

Comment: jQuery is also just javascript in the end. So you can use whatever you found and use it together with your jQuery code.